# Add new field CakePHP Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, cakephp

I have a list of item and retrieving it in PHP array:

```
array(
        'Daging Kambing Beku 2' => array(
            (int) 4 => '80.00',
        ),
        'Daging Rusa' => array(
            (int) 32 => '4000.00'
        ),
        'Sayur Kangkung' => array(
            (int) 31 => '5000.00'
        ),
        'Sayur Sawi' => array(
            (int) 30 => '600.00',
            (int) 29 => '4.00'
        ),
        'Sayur Lemau' => array(
            (int) 28 => '1.00'
        ),
        'Sayur Sayuranj' => array(
            (int) 27 => '1.00'
        ),
        'Sayur Segar ke?' => array(
            (int) 26 => '5.00'
        ),
        'French Fries' => array(
            (int) 25 => '90.00'
        ),
        'Daging Arnab' => array(
            (int) 33 => '5.00'
        ),
        'Daging Kerbaul' => array(
            (int) 34 => '20.00'
        )
    )
```

Array explain :

```
'Daging Kambing Beku 2' => array(
                (int) 4 => '80.00',
            ),
```

'Daging Kambing Beku 2' is the name of item.
(int) 4 is the ID for the items table.
'80.00' is the price .

My problem is,I want to make a function add new Item each time Customer make an order.
I'd try using jquery read the PHP array and to add a list of item when Customer clicking "Add New Item" but it's failed.

I want to do something like this:
https://demo.phppointofsale.com/index.php/sales

Customer can add many Items without submitting page frequently.

I'm using CakePHP for my development.

I'll appreciate any kind of help. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just a reminder, to use php array in js, you need to do some convertion like :

```
<script>
<?php echo "var js_array = ".json_encode($php_array).';'?>
</script>
```